# CSS3 animation does not work in Safari

Tags: html, css, animation, safari

I have made this animation [codepen.io/adsie96/pen/WbzrEG?editors=110](http://codepen.io/adsie96/pen/WbzrEG?editors=110%60) on CodePen and it doesn't work in Safari for me but it worked for a friend of mine, so why is that?

I have no idea please help! What I have seen is the `::before` and `::after` that doesn't work in Safari for me.

Answer (score 0):

Nice code, only thing missing is a "start" value which webkit needs, so add the initial clip value to your `.pulse:after` like this `clip: rect(0, 0, 100px, 0);`

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbjYeK